# Compiling Apache with another glibc version

Tags: compiling, apache-httpd, glibc

My system has an old `glibc` version. I compiled the new version [2.23] into `/FaF/glibc`.

Due to the fact the new `glibc` version is not compatible with SLES 11 SP2 & SP3 I have to use the linker switch [`--rpath=/FaF/glibc/lib`] in order the new version is used in my programs. This works perfectly!

I cannot set the path to the new `glibc` version in the `ld.so.confg` file because then all system programs try to load the new `glibc` version and the system crashes horrible.

**My question:**
Is there a way to compile Apache with the new `glibc` version using the `--rpath` switch?

Comment: Maybe linking it statically? I myself migrated all my inherited SLES to Debian.

Comment: Is this just a "newer is always magically better" thing or do you actually have some reason for installing a newer glibc and compiling apache against it?  What benefit do you expect to gain from doing this?  If you can't clearly articulate (to yourself) any benefit(s) then it's not worth doing.  Use a bleeding-edge distro (like debian testing or unstable) rather than a static/stable one, if that's what you want.

Comment: @cas *"newer is always magically better"* - My system has up to 8! years old libraries. For me it is **now** better and the more convenient way to update the dependencies. Especially when you consider I needed to upgrade Apache to 2.4 and I started to use PHP 7.x. After 2 days & nights I could solve the problem...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was not able to link it statically. There is also the *rule* not to link statically if you can avoid it.

Comment: yes, i can see your point.  spending 2 days and nights compiling stuff is a much better solution and use of time than spending a few minutes typing `apt-get install` or `yum install`.

Comment: @cas I am happy you understand the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer was in the [Apache build documentation - Environment variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/configure.html#env).

In my case the very serious issue is the fact my system [SLES 11 SP2] crashes with the `glibc` version 2.23.

This means I cannot set the path to the new `glibc` libraries in the `ld.so.conf` file.

The only one solution for me is to set `$LDFLAGS` **while running `configure` and `make`** with the following values in order the system can load Apache and all of the new libraries in the correct order and also to set the loader explicitly:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/FaF/lib64 -L/FaF/glibc/lib -L/FaF/openssl-curl/lib 
       -Wl,--rpath=/FaF/glibc/lib -Wl,--rpath=/FaF/lib64
       -Wl,--rpath=/FaF/lib -Wl,--rpath=/FaF/openssl-curl/lib
       -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/lib64/ -Wl,--rpath=/usr/lib64
       -Wl,--rpath=/lib64/ -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/FaF/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
```

All programs using the new `glibc` version are collected in `/FaF`.